# unable to find the directory logstash under '/etc/' after installing logstash

Tags: ubuntu, logstash, elk

I installed logstash 7.9.1 in ubuntu bionic 18.04 machine using following command

```
1.  wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -

2.  sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y

3.   echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main"| sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list

4.  apt update -y

5.  apt install logstash –y
```

After the installation i am able to find the logstash directory in  '/usr/share/logstash', but i am not find the logstah under the directory : '/etc/' where all such configuration and pipeline files said to be available

I am new to logstash and bit confused in configuring these

Appreciated for the help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that the version used to install the Logstash is v7.9.1, however in your 3rd step, the repository used to fetch the version is v6

> 3. echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main"| sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list

Are you sure the package was fetched properly ?